# Animate div element to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to animate the div element to move to the right when the 'sign in' button is clicked.

I have managed to animate it to the right, however some of the element hangs off the browser window.

HTML:

```
<section class="welcome">
        <div class="hero-container">
                <h1 id="welcome">Welcome!</h1>
                <p>Welcome back</p>
                <button id="sign-in">Sign in</button>
                <button id="sign-up">Sign up</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form">
        <form class="sign-in">
            <h1 id="signIn-heading">Sign In</h1>

            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">

            <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password">

        </form>
    </div>

</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#sign-in").click(function(){

//below I am retrieving the width of the body
var $width= $("body").width();

//assigning the body with to the animate method
$(".hero-container").animate({"left": $width}, "slow");

$("#welcome").html("Sign In");
$(".form").show();

});
```

> This is what I want to achieve 
>     https://ibb.co/gmqZCkg
>
> This is the problem I am getting (As you can see once the element is animated it hangs off the browser)
>     https://ibb.co/WP4vHLj

Comment: can you post your css code as well, or a library that you're using for example `bootstrap`, or attach a snippet so we can properly reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$("#sign-in").click(function(){

//below I am retrieving the width of the body
var $width= $("body").width()/2;

//assigning the body with to the animate method
$(".hero-container").animate({"left": $width}, "slow");

$("#welcome").html("Sign In");
$(".form").show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="welcome">
        <div class="hero-container">
                <h1 id="welcome">Welcome!</h1>
                <p>Welcome back</p>
                <button id="sign-in">Sign in</button>
                <button id="sign-up">Sign up</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form">
        <form class="sign-in">
            <h1 id="signIn-heading">Sign In</h1>

            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">

            <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password">

        </form>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount your animating by (width) is the width of the body. You'll need to get the width of the #sign-in element instead.